# Group by email and question_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent, laravel-collection

Im developing a small app that is able to create surveys, and in these surveys have question, where a question could me a simple input form or in a form of checkboxes.

My issue is related with the multiple values (radio inputs), i have a table called "answers" with the above structure:

```
Answers (table):
- id;
- question_id;
- answer;
- email;
```

In one of my backend pages i have a table where i loop the question and the answers.

Is working fine, but the problem is when i have multiple values, the header table (questions) starts being less the the coluns body answers, and this is because of the number of answers.

I created this query using eloquent and collection where first i orderByGroup of 'email'.

```
$survey = Survey::find($id);

return $survey->answers->groupBy('email');
```

It gives me a array of grouped answers from each email, this is great, but now i need to group inside the email groups the questions, in my case 'question_id'. But isnt working for me.

I tried something like

```
 return $survey->answers->groupBy('email')->groupBy('question_id');
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`groupBy()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L1309) method accepts multiple parameters and iterating over them:

```
public function groupBy(...$groups)
{
    foreach ($groups as $group)
```

Do this:

```
return $survey->answers->groupBy('email', 'question_id');
```

Comment: Already tried it, but the 2 records with the same question_id are not grouped.